# Query a database and generate an ArrayList object

Tags: java, sql

Hi I have a problem I am having trouble solving here it is:

Write the code for the **getPeople ()** method so that it constructs and returns an
**ArrayList** of **Person** type objects retrieved from a database.

An object of type **java.sql.Connection** has been initialized.
The SQL database contains a people table with 3 columns: *id* (autoincrementing integer)
, *first_name* (varchar), *last_name* (varchar).

Using the **Connection** object, retrieve all the records from the table, and for each
record use the corresponding fields to create an object of type **Person**.Add each
**Person** type object thus created in your **ArrayList**.
Return the resulting list.

Here is the code that must be completed:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql. *;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util. *;

public class ExerciseImpl {

    public void runExercise (String [] argv) throws Exception {
    }

    public ArrayList <Person> getPeople () throws Exception {
        Connection conn = this.getCandidateConnection ();
        / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /

        / **** Enter your code here **** /

        / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /
    }

   
}

class Person {
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    Person (int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I came up with:

```
public class ExerciseImpl {

    public void runExercise (String [] argv) throws Exception {
    }

    public ArrayList <Person> getPeople () throws Exception {
          ResultSet resultSet=null;
       try( Connection conn = this.getCandidateConnection();
            Statement statement= conn.createStatement();){
           String selectSql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name from people";
           resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);
 
    }catch (SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
 
        }

        / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /
    }

   
}

class Person {
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    Person (int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Honestly, I couldn't complete much (I just created the **getCandidateConnection ()**  method without a body)
because I don't know how
complete it and also for the rest, I do not know how to query a database in a java program.
Basically, I have a hard time with this problem.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You changed the code below the line that says "DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING"? Is this for a class or for a job? What do you expect to do with the next assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated code looks **much** better. You still moved where the code gets the `Connection`. I moved that back, and tweaked it a tiny bit. Get the `id`, `first_name` and `last_name` from the `ResultSet`. Then instantiate a `Person` instance and add it to a `List`. Finally, return the `List`. Something like,

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPeople() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = this.getCandidateConnection();
     /* ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- */
    final String selectSql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name " //
            + "FROM people ORDER BY last_name, first_name";
    ArrayList<Person> al = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement(); //
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql)) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String firstName = resultSet.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = resultSet.getString("last_name");
            al.add(new Person(id, firstName, lastName));
        }
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    return al;
    /* ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- */
}
```

Comment: That's good but in the selectSql , i think it is not necessary to add ORDER BY last_name,first_name, because they didn't ask to sort in the assigment ,anyway your code is better than mine,i will test it and then validate it

Comment: i added the catch method from the exception throwing and then i added the getCandidateConnection() method but i don't know how to complete the getCandidateConnection() body